# unable to load file in php using use method

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway

i am try to integrate elavon payment gateway using javascript library and php.
i have php library for elavon payment gateway but as per demo code from elavon they provide something like bellow

```html
<?php
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

use com\realexpayments\hpp\sdk\domain\HppResponse;
use com\realexpayments\hpp\sdk\RealexHpp;
use com\realexpayments\hpp\sdk\RealexValidationException;
use com\realexpayments\hpp\sdk\RealexException;

$realexHpp = new RealexHpp("Shared Secret");
// grab the response sent by the client-side library
$responseJson = $_POST['hppResponse'];

try {
    // create the response object
    $hppResponse = $realexHpp->responseFromJson($responseJson);
    $result = $hppResponse->getResult(); // 00
    $message = $hppResponse->getMessage(); // [ test system ] Authorised
    $authCode = $hppResponse->getAuthCode(); // 12345

    return $hppResponse;
}
catch (RealexValidationException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
catch (RealexException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

i have all the file inside this diretory

> com-realexpayments-hpp-sdk

but when i try to load above code in my server its return 500 error so please help me to load that library in core php
thanks.

Comment: Did you run the composer install command?

Comment: how can i do this can you explain me ?

Comment: - Install composer to your machine, instructions: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
- Then run composer install in the project directory

Better yet, read the README that comes with the example code for the elavon payment gateway? I'm sure it'll explain that you'll need to run composer install first.